# Creating log functionalities with Genexus

Tags: genexus

It's my first time with Genexus and I want to know how to create log functionalities.

I created a transaction object "Logs" but I don't need any user interface interaction. Also, I want to insert record to the "Logs" table directly inside events like "After Trn".

How can I accomplish that? What's the best approach?

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a procedure with the information to be logged, for example `logAdd`

If it is a web application you can extract the user from the websession, if it is a win application you need to pass it on parms.

Then you call the procedure on BeforeComplete of every transaction.

Web Example:

```
logAdd.Call(&Pgmname, "Clients", CliId.ToString(), &Mode) on BeforeComplete;
```

It is important that the `logAdd` procedure has the `Commit on exit` property in `false`.
This way the information will be logged only if the transaction is confirmed.

**Update - getting old values in your logging procedure**

To get the previous values of a transaction you can take advantage of bussiness components.
After setting your transaction as a `Bussiness Component` you put the following rules on your transaction:

```
[WEB] {
    &Clients.load(CliId) if update on BeforeValidate;
    logClients.Call(CliId, &Clients, &Mode) on BeforeComplete;
}
```

`&Clients` is a variable based on your Bussiness Component type.

In `prc:logClients` you can access all the old values through `&Clients.Att.GetOldValue()`, and the new values through a regular `For Each`

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks. When I access the attributes on BeforeComplete, I get the new value. I'm using a "Previous State" log table. Is there a way to get the value before the commit?